# Use JQuery To Display Placeholder Text In A Password Field, And Then Remove It When Text Is Entered

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to emulate the effect Twitter uses on it's homepage. It displays "Username" and "Password" in both login fields, and then when you start to type it removes the text. I haven't been successful so far, my best attempt displayed text inside the password field, but displayed it as if a password had been entered.

Is there a JQuery plugin available to do this? I have seen one where it requires two password fields, and displays only one at a time. This isn't suitable.

Comment: HTML5's placeholder Attribute is what youre looking for, no need for jQuery here

Comment: Would this render in browsers that don't recognise HTML5 though? Such as IE8?

Comment: no, IE8 does not support placeholder attribute - note that you have tagged your question html5

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/placeholder

Comment: @Muleskinner I tagged it HTML5 because the site is built using HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a jquery watermark plugin:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: This does what I need, and works on all browsers (even the non-HTML5 ones). It's a bit buggy at the moment but I'm working them out. Cheers! :)

Comment: cool, glad it helped, those are pretty nifty and you can customize the css quite a lot!

Answer (score 3):

We found the best jQuery plugin to be [jQuery Placeholder Plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin) (a.k.a. jquery.placeholder.js). It's the best for the same reasons as the features it advertises:

> - Works in all A-grade browsers, including IE6.
> - Automatically checks if the browser natively supports the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute for `input` and `textarea` elements. If this is the case, the plugin won’t do anything. If `@placeholder` is only supported for `input` elements, the plugin will leave those alone and apply to `textarea`s exclusively. (This is the case for Safari 4, Opera 11.00, and possibly other browsers.)
> - Caches the results of its two feature tests in `jQuery.fn.placeholder.input` and `jQuery.fn.placeholder.textarea`. For example, if `@placeholder` is natively supported for `input` elements, `jQuery.fn.placeholder.input` will be `true`. After loading the plugin, you can re-use these properties in your own code.
> - Makes sure it never causes duplicate IDs in your DOM, even in browsers that need an extra `input` element to fake `@placeholder` for password inputs. This means you can safely do stuff like:

Answer (score 0):

I use [this plugin](http://www.iliadraznin.com/examples/better-jquery-placeholder-script/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $('input[placeholder]').each(function() {

                var input = $(this);

                $(input).val(input.attr('placeholder'));

                $(input).focus(function() {
                    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val('');
                    }
                });

                $(input).blur(function() {
                    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        ;
    </script>
```